# What transistor is this with SMD marking 72C9?

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

I am not sure what this part could be, and using some SMD codes on the web, didn't help.

The case size is either SC70 or SOT-523

[image: photo of unknown component]

Comment: smd codes are vendor specific and many chinese minor suppliers may not be listed, so unless you can examine the circuit requirements and match those, you may be SOL unless some expert comp. eng. finds it, I’m on a painting break

Answer (score 2):

It's possible it's a 2N7002. A number of manufacturers have similar numbers.